# SQL Server 2008 R2: Tricky query - Finding certain rows in segments of rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I don't know how to explain this in a general way, so allow me to give an example.

```
SELECT ParentId, Id, Number
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY ParentId, Id
```

gives

```
ParentId Id     Number
2997    1145445 400
2997    1145449 400
2997    1145577 400
2997    1146518 405
2999    1145470 400
2999    1145502 400
2999    1145504 400
3016    1145633 400
3016    1145636 400
3016    1145677 400
3016    1145686 405
3037    1145885 400
3037    1145906 405
3037    1145922 400
3037    1145925 400
3162    1147324 400
3162    1147327 400
3162    1147329 400
3162    1147332 400
3162    1147334 405
3162    1147339 400
3162    1147341 405
3162    1147345 406
3162    1147347 410
```

(this is just a subset of the real data, but enough to explain the problem).

The problem:

A query (as elegant and efficient as possible, preferably without sub-queries, cursors etc.) that selects exactly all rows with `Number = 400` but with the following columns added:

`Id_405`: The `Id` of the row with `Number = 405` and the same `ParentId` between this 400 and the next 400, ordered as above by Id. It is guaranteed that there is at most one 405. `Id_405` is null if there is no such 405.

`Id_406`: The `Id` of the row with `Number = 406` and the same `ParentId` between this 400 and the next 400, ordered as above by Id. It is guaranteed that there is at most one 406. `Id_406` is null if there is no such 406.

`Id_410`: The Id of the row with `Number = 410` and the same `ParentId` between this 400 and the next 400, ordered as above by Id. It is guaranteed that there is at most one 406. `Id_410` is null if there is no such 410.

With the above example data, the query would return:

```
ParentId    Id  Number  Id_405  Id_406  Id_410
2997    1145445 400     null    null    null
2997    1145449 400     null    null    null
2997    1145577 400     1146518 null    null
2999    1145470 400     null    null    null
2999    1145502 400     null    null    null
2999    1145504 400     null    null    null
3016    1145633 400     null    null    null
3016    1145636 400     null    null    null
3016    1145677 400     1145686 null    null
3037    1145885 400     1145906 null    null
3037    1145922 400     null    null    null
3037    1145925 400     null    null    null
3162    1147324 400     null    null    null
3162    1147327 400     null    null    null
3162    1147329 400     null    null    null
3162    1147332 400     1147334 null    null
3162    1147339 400     1147341 1147345 1147347
```

Please help!

Comment: Concept of Id_405, Id_406 and Id_410 is not clear. Explain clearly so that people can answer this.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: I am not sure what is unclear about Id_405, Id_406 and Id_410? They are explained separately above and an example is given. I don't know what else to add without knowing what you think is unclear.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 as stated in the title.

Answer (score 2):

The solution posted by Dan does not actually produce the correct result - so in a similar style I've posted one that appears to produce the correct result.

<kbd>[`Fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9377/1)</kbd>

```
WITH r AS (
  SELECT t1.parentid
       , t1.id
       , t1.number
       , ISNULL(t2.id,2147483647) as id2
       , row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.parentid, t1.id ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id)  
  FROM          t t1 
    LEFT JOIN   t t2 
      ON        t1.id < t2.id 
      AND       t1.parentid = t2.parentid 
      AND       t2.number = 400
  WHERE         t1.number = 400
)
SELECT r.parentid, r.id, r.number, t_405.id as id_405, t_406.id as id_406, t_410.id as id_410
FROM          r
  LEFT JOIN   t        t_405
    ON        t_405.parentid = r.parentid
    AND       t_405.id BETWEEN r.id AND r.id2
    AND       t_405.number = 405
  LEFT JOIN   t        t_406
    ON        t_406.parentid = r.parentid
    AND       t_406.id BETWEEN r.id AND r.id2
    AND       t_406.number = 406
  LEFT JOIN   t        t_410
    ON        t_410.parentid = r.parentid
    AND       t_410.id BETWEEN r.id AND r.id2
    AND       t_410.number = 410
WHERE r.row = 1
```

Comment: I check the result of Dan's answer, So what is its problem? ;).

Comment: I see no differences between the results your query returns versus mine.  Both match the desire results.

Comment: @Dan row 1145885 should contain the value for 405, but it goes to 1145925 (under the same parent id)

sorry couldn't comment on your post.

Comment: @user4882995, thanks for pointing that out.  I twice looked for differences and did not see it.

Comment: @user4882995, I went ahead and just deleted my answer.  You incorporated the important elements of my query in your solution and addressed the abovementioned issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can number your rows separately and then join on those rankings like:

```
SELECT 
    t.parentid, t.id, t.number, t1.id, t2.id, t3.id 
FROM 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parentid ORDER BY id DESC) rn
     FROM t
     WHERE number = 400) t
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parentid ORDER BY id DESC) rn
     FROM t
     WHERE number = 405) t1 ON t.parentid = t1.parentid AND t.rn = t1.rn
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parentid ORDER BY id DESC) rn
     FROM t
     WHERE number = 406) t2 ON t.parentid = t2.parentid AND t.rn = t2.rn
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parentid ORDER BY id DESC) rn
     FROM t
     WHERE number = 410) t3 ON t.parentid = t3.parentid AND t.rn = t3.rn
ORDER BY t.parentid, t.rn DESC
```

Here is the <kbd>[`fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06501/3)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa1ab/9)</kbd>

I don't know if you consider this elegant and efficient, but the result is the same:

```
select * 
from sometable d400
outer apply (
  select top 1 id id_400n
  from sometable 
  where sometable.number=400
    and sometable.parentid=d400.parentid
    and sometable.id>d400.id
  order by id
) d400n 
outer apply (
  select top 1 id id_405
  from sometable
  where sometable.number=405
    and sometable.parentid=d400.parentid
    and sometable.id between d400.id and coalesce(d400n.id_400n,9999999)
  order by id
) d405 
outer apply (
  select top 1 id id_406
  from sometable
  where sometable.number=406
    and sometable.parentid=d400.parentid
    and sometable.id between d400.id and coalesce(d400n.id_400n,9999999)
  order by id
) d406
outer apply (
  select top 1 id id_410
  from sometable
  where sometable.number=410
    and sometable.parentid=d400.parentid
    and sometable.id between d400.id and coalesce(d400n.id_400n,9999999)
  order by id
) d410
where d400.number=400
order by d400.id
```

Comment: Result of your query is not same as the OP's result, check it please ;).

Comment: @shA.t it may miss a order by but thats the only difference. and i seriously doubt that "I don't know that do you consider this elegant and efficient" is better english than mine.

Comment: At first, use `order by d400.ParentId, d400.id` instead of that and then you have `id400n` column in your result that I think OP needs to remove that; and as soon as you want to edit do it ;).